# How to replace time series labels on x-axis with a decreasing integer variable?

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

I have the following question: I would like to plot time-series data. But instead of putting the time as x-axis labels (hours:minutes), I want a decreasing integer variable that represents the number of hours before a specific event takes place in a decreasing order. For instance; if my dummy data contains time series data of 30 hours, I want the following on the x axis:

```
seq(from = 5, to = 0, by = -1)
```

How can I do this without editing or scaling the data? I tried the scale_x_discrete function, but I could not get that to work. And to make it more difficult, the time series data are not linear; so adding a column to the data frame would not solve it.

Example code:

```
#Import libraries
library(reshape2)[enter image description here][1]
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

#Set up data frame
time.points.char.v <- c("2017-03-14 08:00:00 GMT",
                        "2017-03-14 08:15:00 GMT",
                        "2017-03-14 08:30:00 GMT",
                        "2017-03-14 09:00:00 GMT",
                        "2017-03-14 09:30:00 GMT",
                        "2017-03-14 10:22:00 GMT",
                        "2017-03-14 11:25:00 GMT",
                        "2017-03-14 12:32:00 GMT",
                        "2017-03-14 12:40:00 GMT",
                        "2017-03-14 12:45:00 GMT")

time.points.POSIXct.v <- as.POSIXct(time.points.char.v,
                                format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

#Set up data frame
prices.time.df <- data.frame(time = time.points.POSIXct.v,
                             price.1 = rnorm(n = 10, 
                                             mean = 5, 
                                             sd = 2))

#Melt data frame
prices.time.melt.df <- melt(data = prices.time.df, 
                            id.vars = "time", 
                            variable.name = "variable")

#Plot data frame
ggplot(data = prices.time.melt.df,
       mapping = aes(x = time, 
                     y = value,
                     group = variable,
                     colour = variable)) +
  geom_line(na.rm = T) + 
  geom_point(na.rm = T) +
  facet_grid(variable ~ ., drop = F, scale = "free_y") +
  xlab("Time") +
  ylab("Variables") +
  scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = ("3 hour"),
                   minor_breaks = NULL,
                   labels = date_format("%H"),
  ) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 11) +
  theme(legend.position="none") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 25, vjust = 1.0, hjust = 1.0))
```

[image]

Thanks in advance!

(Edited the question on 2018-02-08 to include the non-linear time series data)

Answer (score 1):

One option is to add `hours_before_event` column to the data frame before plotting.

```
prices.time.melt.df$hours_before_event <-
  difftime(
    max(prices.time.melt.df$time),
    prices.time.melt.df$time, units="hours"
  )

ggplot(
  data = prices.time.melt.df,
  mapping = aes(
    x = hours_before_event, 
    y = value,
    group = variable,
    colour = variable
  )
) +
  geom_line(na.rm = T) + 
  geom_point(na.rm = T) +
  facet_grid(variable ~ ., drop = F, scale = "free_y") +
  scale_x_reverse() +
  xlab("Time") +
  ylab("Variables") +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 11) +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 25, vjust = 1.0, hjust = 1.0))
```

[image]

**Update**

Using your new data, I ran the above code and got the figure below.
Isn't this what you want?

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, what if the time series data is not linear? I have edited my question.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for!